# http error 400 Bad Request on name but IP address works

Tags: http, hostname, 400

I have got a Vodafone "EasyBox 904 xDSL" router which has a LAN facing administration interface on http (not https) on port 80. I can access it fine when I use

```
http://[ip of the router]
```

For convenience I added an entry into our local DNS server which points to that IP.

Pinging that address confirms that the name lookup works:

```
ping router.our.domain
PING router.our.domain ([ip of the router]) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from _gateway ([ip of the router]): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.448 ms
```

(note the "_gateway" in the response, no idea where that comes from)
but when I try to use that name in the web browser, I get an http error 400:

```
http://router.our.domain
```

Just to be sure this isn't an artefact of the web browser I used w3m:

```
400 Bad Request

Your Client sent a query that this server could not understand

Reason: Invalid HOST
```

The browser is connecting directly, there is no proxy involved.

I guess this has something to do with the router's webserver trying to match the name to a local host name and failing. But that's only a guess. I could not find a setting for a host name in the router configuration.

Any hints on what I could try to find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like web server in the device doesn't like `host` field in the HTTP request and supports the connections only by ip address or by some special host name.

[The documentation](https://webadmin.vodafone.de/download/pdf/HB-EasyBox_904_xDSL.pdf) says to connect to addministrative web interface you should use domain name `easy.box` or ip address `192.168.2.1`.

The `_gateway` in the ping output comes from reverse address lookup (resolve the domain name by ip address) with built-in dns server. You can avoid the reverse lookup with `-n` option of ping.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately http://easy.box doesn't work: Name lookup fails. The IP adress from the documentation also does not work because we do not use the default class C network and the router also is not the dhcp server. I guess I must live with using the router's IP.

Comment: You can add `easy.box` record into `hosts` file.

Comment: Yes, but that would only work on that computer.